# My php function will not be called

Tags: php, android, mysql, string

I have the following code to connect between mysql database and android.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

//if there is some error connecting to the database
//with die we will stop the further execution by displaying a message causing the error
if ($conn) {
  $response["Connection"] = 1;
}
else {
  $response["Connection"] = 0;
}
$userID= $_POST['user_id'];

function recordExists() {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM user_table";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $response["found"] = "i am here";

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $response["found"] = $row['user_id'];
    if($row['user_id']==$userID){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

  // $result_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  //
  // if($result_num_rows>0) {
  //   return true; // The record(s) do exist
  // }
  // return false; // No record found
}
$exists=recordExists();
if ($exists) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE $userID";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
  $Nickname = array();
  if ($row['nickname'] == NULL){
    array_push($response["nickname"], "False");
  }else{
    array_push($response["nickname"], $row["nickname"]);
  }
  $response["Sync"] = "Already Added";
  echo (json_encode($response));
} else {
  $UserToBeAdded= $_POST['user_id'];
  $NameToBeAdded= $_POST['name'];
  $EmailToBeAdded= $_POST['email'];
  $UserToBeAdded2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $UserToBeAdded);
  $NameToBeAdded2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $NameToBeAdded);
  $EmailToBeAdded2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $EmailToBeAdded);
  $sql_query = "insert into user_table (user_id, name, email) values ('$UserToBeAdded2', '$NameToBeAdded2', '$EmailToBeAdded2');";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
  $response["ID"] = $UserToBeAdded2;
  $response["Name"] = $NameToBeAdded2;
  $response["Email"] = $EmailToBeAdded2;
  $response["Sync"] = "Just Added";
  $response["nickname"] = "False";
  echo (json_encode($response));
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

from the above code, i can receive responses from the php side. however the following response is not received.

```
$response["found"] = "i am here";
```

if u see from my code above, basically the function recordExists() will definitely be called. however the response " i am here" is not encoded in JSON when i emulate the android app. anything wrong?

Comment: Variable scope issue and sql injection vulnerabilities

Comment: Your variable scope is only within the function itself. You can either return the value as needed (other than true/false) or set a new function that does DB handling and call it separately, which is a better way to do it. Also, not sure on what use setting that var is, you can simply check if you get a true or false (or value) from the function outside the function

Answer (score 0):

try to declare the response variable above all functions. so add `$response=array();`on top of the file.

here you can read up about the scope of php variables:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Adding that at the top of the file wont resolve the variable scope issue, which you know about as you linked to variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable scope issue with the connection variable. Pass the connection variable as a parameter.

```
recordExists($conn);
```

Also use prepared statements to prevent sql injection attacks.